# Android TelephonyManager

Tags: android

I'm always receiving this bug:
12-15 09:46:48.434: E/TelephonyManager(5127): getDefaultSim is sim1

when I call:

```
TelephonyManager mTelephonyMgr = (TelephonyManager) this.getSystemService(Context.TELEPHONY_SERVICE);

if( mTelephonyMgr != null && mTelephonyMgr.getDeviceId() != null )
      deviceImei = mTelephonyMgr.getDeviceId();
if (mTelephonyMgr != null && mTelephonyMgr.getSimState() == TelephonyManager.SIM_STATE_READY)
country = mTelephonyMgr.getSimCountryIso();
```

Comment: Please see my answer, it will solve your problem.

Answer (score -1):

There are 3 different categories ...

```
1) Features supported and documented

2) Features available and un-documented

3) Features unavailable
```

So the dual sim features are available but not documented and hence not officially supported.

Having said that it does not mean that it will not be usable, It just means that android(or for that matter google or even manufaturer) is not liable to support your apps functionality.

But it might just work, for eg. the contacts is a similar thing.

You might then ask up how would everyone know about the features if in case it is not documented.. Hey android is open source .. go look into code and find it for yourself . Thats what I guess the multi sim developers did.

Comment: then how we get these information if device is dual sim or many sim's like Chinese device which have 6-7 sim slot.is this future android specific or device manufacture specific ?

Comment: if we want other sim info then we have any other API for this apart from telephony manager.plz if you have any reference for this type of API's then share it.Thanks

Comment: @ρяσѕρєяK If the OEM has exposed an API you can use it, otherwise there isn't a method.

Comment: go for SubscriptionManager api rather then telephony manager but on above api level 22 for second sim information